# Making a text blend in the background to hide it

Tags: html, css

sorry if my title is not clear but I do not know how to put words on my request.

I did a bit of research but since Im not sure what I am supposed to look for, i couldn't find much.

Im trying to reproduce the following effect (Bottom part only)

[image]

Im basically trying to create a DIV, where the text will basically remove the background color of the DIV itself. . by ??blending?? in the background ?

Sorry if my question is not clear again, im trying to do my best to learn :)

Comment: As SO isn't a code writing service, I would recommend posting anything that you have tried. Otherwise you will get downvoted and the question will most likely get closed.

Comment: I cannot try something If i do not know what im supposed to go for since i don't even know if there is a specific name for the task I want to do.
Im not asking for a code in specific, but maybe some indications on what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use this in your CSS. And then set the background image.

```
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Here is an example
https://codepen.io/Joseph-Yaconelli/pen/JjeRrJQ